# How to generate models from OpenAPI with ref

Tags: openapi, swagger-codegen

I have a file with ref to the other file in this folder:

```
$ref: "./inbound_api.yaml#/components/schemas/BadRequestResponse"
```

When I run

```
oapi-codegen -generate types -o pkg/models/inbound/booking.go -package models booking.yaml
```

It can't resolve the file

```
error generating code: error creating operation definitions: error generating response definitions: error generating request body definition: error turning reference (./inbound_api.yaml#/components/schemas/Response) into a Go type: unrecognized external reference './inbound_api.yaml'; please provide the known import for this reference using option --import-mapping
```

How to provide the mapping? Do I need to do it for the file in the same folder?